# is there any way to insert empty value to attribute in sun one LDAP using java

Tags: java, openldap, unboundid-ldap-sdk

please help me to get any possible was to insert empty values in LDAP using java/sample LDAP script. i have referred many cases but i didn't find any feasible solution .

Thanks in Advance ..

Comment: There is no such thing as an empty attribute value in LDAP, let alone Java.

Comment: Actually there are syntaxes that allow an empty string as a value, DN being one of them.

Comment: @LudovicPoitou could an empty string as a value also cause [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39372374/5606016) issue?

Comment: @A_Di-Matteo, NO, the issue  you're referring to is really that the entry cannot be found and none of the parents either on that server (or the server doesn't return any matching parent on purpose).

Answer (score 0):

You can only add empty values to attributes whose syntax allow it : IA5String and DNs.
An example of command line use :

```
$ ldapmodify -h localhost -p 1389 -D "cn=directory manager" -w secret12
dn: cn=G,dc=example,dc=com
changetype: modify
add: member
member:
-

Processing MODIFY request for cn=G,dc=example,dc=com
MODIFY operation successful for DN cn=G,dc=example,dc=com
```

With Java, you will probably need an LDAP client library such as OpenDJ SDK, and build a modify operation where you add an attribute and the value is an empty string. I don't think you can do it with JNDI, but I could be proved wrong.